# Using missingno but got incorrect result

Tags: python, matplotlib, missing-data

I have a dataframe for air pollution with several missing gaps like this:

```
Date             AMB_TEMP      CO         PM10       PM2.5
2010-01-01 0         8         10         ...          15
2010-01-01 1         10        15         ...          20
...
2010-01-02 0                   5          ...           
2010-01-02 1                              ...          20
...
2010-01-03 1         4         13         ...          34
```

To specify, here's the data link: [shorturl.at/blBN1](http://shorturl.at/blBN1)

Take the first column "ambient temperature"(amb_temp) for instance:

There are given missing info below:

1. Length of time series: **87648**
2. Number of Missing Values:**746**
3. Percentage of Missing Values: **0.85 %**
4. Number of Gaps: **136**
5. Average Gap Size: **5.485294**
6. Longest NA gap (series of consecutive NAs):  **32**
7. Most frequent gap size (series of consecutive NA series): **1(occurring 50 times)**

I want to plot the overview of missing value and what I've done is:

```py
    import missingno as msno
    missing_plot = msno.matrix(df , freq='Y')
```

and got a figure like this:
[image: result]

Obviously, in the first column, the AMB_TEMP is not consistent to the real. Only three horizontal lines but actually it should be at least 136.

**Update: Thanks to Patrick, I also tried only one column, and nothing improved.
[image: Temperature]

Is there any error from the code or else..?

Comment: My guess is that the figure is too small with respect to the length of the time series to make all the 136 gaps appear, the three lines are probably series of several gaps grouped together which makes them visible. If you double or triple the figure height you might see more lines appear.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it might not be the reason. Because I have tried only one column and got a figure updated in my post. Moreover, I have checked the visible lines finding they're tiny gap with only one missing value.

Comment: By _double or triple the figure height_ I meant trying something like `msno.matrix(df, figsize=(10, 150))` which gives you [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0rbl.png) where you can see that more lines are visible. The problem is that there are 87648 rows so the few hundred missing values will not all appear on a small figure. If you make the figure even taller or if you limit the number of rows of the df, you can see most (or even all) the white lines for each missing value, like this: `msno.matrix(df.iloc[0:10000], figsize=(10, 150))`, [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ2Ay.png).